# Avoid overlapping in highchart bubble chart

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I'm trying to represent a few series as a Bubble Chart, but I don't know how to represent the bubbles in different X positions when they belong to the same category. Let's take the following example

[image: Bubbles Chart]
When the chart is represented in bars or columns, there is no overlapping, but when i choose bubbles, every bubble is drawn in the same position.

I want something like this:

[image: Bubbles Chart Not Overlapping]

How can I achieve this?? Here you can find the example:

```
chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    plotBorderWidth: 1
},
xAxis: {
    labels: {
    overflow: 'justify'
    },
    lineColor: "#1E232A",
    tickColor: "#1E232A",
    type: "category"
    },
series: [{
        name: "BLUE",
    data: [
        { y: 65, z: 13.8, name: 'Belgium' },
        { y: 32.9, z: 14.7, name: 'Germany' },
        { y: 11.5, z: 15.8, name: 'Finland' }
    ]
},
{
    name: "BLACK",
    data: [
        { y: 65, z: 44.8, name: 'Belgium' },
        { y: 32.9, z: 66.7, name: 'Germany' },
        { y: 11.5, z: 77.8, name: 'Finland' }
    ]
},
{
    name: "GREEN",
    data: [
        { y: 65, z: 54.8, name: 'Belgium' },
        { y: 32.9, z: 56.7, name: 'Germany' },
        { y: 11.5, z: 37.8, name: 'Finland' }
    ]
}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/433bqnea/

Comment: check this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/m4xzahbc/ using stacking and inverted option of highcharts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see/find there is no direct supported way to do this. The closest I think you can come is either specify `x` values for each point, or for each series with `pointPlacement`. I made an example using the `pointPlacement`:

```
series: [{
  name: "BLUE",
  pointPlacement: -0.25, //added this
  data: [
    { y: 65, z: 13.8, name: 'Belgium' },
    { y: 32.9, z: 14.7, name: 'Germany' },
    { y: 11.5, z: 15.8, name: 'Finland' }
  ]
},
{
  name: "BLACK",
  data: [
    { y: 65, z: 44.8, name: 'Belgium' },
    { y: 32.9, z: 66.7, name: 'Germany' },
    { y: 11.5, z: 77.8, name: 'Finland' }
  ]
},
{
  name: "GREEN",
  pointPlacement: 0.25, //added this
  data: [
    { y: 65, z: 54.8, name: 'Belgium' },
    { y: 32.9, z: 56.7, name: 'Germany' },
    { y: 11.5, z: 37.8, name: 'Finland' }
  ]
}]
```

The above will look like this:
[image: Example]

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/433bqnea/3/

**API on pointPlacement**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.pointPlacement

Comment: Thanx for this ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue of overlapping of items at different level. What I did to resolve is group the items on the basis of property where it was overlapping and then added jittering affect by adding some minor value to x and y coordinates of overlapping items.